# Creating a selector factory with createSelector in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript-typings, reselect, react-typescript

Creating selectors like this:

```js
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

export interface Node {
  nodeId: number
  nodeName: string
}

export type NodeState = {
  nodes: Node[];
  text: string;
};

const nodeListState = (state) => state.nodeList;


const byKey = (key: keyof NodeState) => createSelector(
  nodeListState, (nodeList: NodeState) => nodeList[key],
);

export const getNodes = byKey('nodes');
export const getText = byKey('text');
```

Elsewhere, using the selectors:

```js
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

const nodes = useSelector(selectors.getNodes);

nodes.map(...)
```

This results in the error:

```
Property 'map' does not exist on type 'string | Node[]'.
  Property 'map' does not exist on type 'string'.  TS2339
```

The variable nodes is actually an array. Am I going about this all wrong? What's the correct way to set up a function that creates selectors by key in TS?

Comment: what is `nodeListState`? AFAIK `createSelector()` accepts one or more functions.

Comment: try removing `nodeListState,` (if it's not a function)

Comment: You can try `export const getNodes = (byKey('nodes') as (nodeList: NodeState) =>  Node[])` As a side note; you can name your selectors anything you want but the convention is that the name start with `select` so `selectNodes` would be a better name for your selector.

Comment: `nodeListState` just selects a slice of the state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening here is that typescript is not able to distinguish between `byKey('nodes')` and `byKey('text')`.  They both return the same type, which is a selector that selects either the text `string` or the nodes `Node[]`.  Thus `const nodes = useSelector(selectors.getNodes)` returns the union `string | Node[]` and you get an error that `string` is not an array.

One way to fix this is to ditch `byKey` and create the two selectors separately.

But we can make `byKey` work properly by making it a generic function which depends on the specific key that it was called with.  That way we know that `byKey('nodes')` selects the `'nodes'` property.

If you apply proper typing to `nodeListState`, you don't actually need to specify the argument for the second selector as `nodeList: NodeState` since it can be inferred based on the return type of the first selector.

```
const nodeListState = (state: {nodeList: NodeState}) => state.nodeList;

const byKey = <K extends keyof NodeState>(key: K) => createSelector(
  nodeListState, 
  (nodeList) => nodeList[key],
);
```

Now `getNodes` selects `Node[]` and `getText` selects `string`.